# Construction of a homogeneous Moran set

Tags: set-theory, mg.metric-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, fractals

Fix a positive integer $N\ge 2$, for $n \in \mathbb{N}$, denote
$$\Sigma=\{0,1,\dots,N-1\},\\
\Sigma^n=\{(\omega_1,\dots,\omega_n):\omega\in\Sigma, i=1,\dots,n\}.$$
Let $p>2$ be a positive integer. Write
$$W_p=\{(0,a_1,\dots,a_{p-2},N-1)\in \Sigma^p:a_i\in \Sigma \quad for \quad all\quad i\ge1 \}.$$
For a fixed $\alpha$ and a sufficiently large integer $n_0=n_0(p)$, we can  define $N_k$ and $l_k$.
For $k \ge 1$, let
$$
w_p\in {W_p}$$
\begin{matrix}
\mathcal{W_k}={\underbrace {w_p\dots w_p}\\N_k times} 0^{l_k}1^{[\alpha(n_0+k)]}.
\end{matrix}
where $[x]$ denotes the integer part of $x$. Then we define the set as follows:
$$E_p=\{0.x_1x_2\dots\in(0,1]:w_k\in \mathcal{W_k},\forall k\ge 1\}.$$

My question is how to regard $E_p$ as a homogeneous Moran set and how to construct this Moran set?